# I am trying to install firebase@4.2.0 and angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 using npm but getting the follwoing error

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, angularfire2

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.1.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.1.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.1.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@5.1.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.1.2
```

and the below dependencies are missing:

```
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
```

can someone help!!

Comment: Are you using Cloud9?

Comment: @makah no, I am not using cloud9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install those packages to use angular at all.

```
npm install --save @angular/common @angular/compiler @angular/core @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
```

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "5.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
"@angular/core": "5.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
"@angular/http": "5.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
"@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
"firebase": "^4.11.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.18" }
```